# Adapting StanfordCoreNLP to process noisy web text?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I've been trying out the StanfordCoreNLP NER and everything manually on the website, and it seems they depend on very specific/proper English cues to detect entities, for example. When dealing with web text, though, where you could have some text like

---

John Doe

Assistant Professor of Computer Science

Stanford University

---

StanfordNLP seems to have some trouble (labeling the whole thing as one organization due to lack of prepositions/punctuation). Is there anything I can do to allow NER to better handle this kind of text (e.g. program some pre-processing of text)?

Comment: But the whole thing is not one organisation! I just tried your example in their online demo and it correctly identifies "John Doe" as a person and "Stanford university" as an organisation.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice that there were multiple classifiers as I was using the default 7-class; 3 seems to perform best with a general model.. is there any way to use all the tags of the 7-class while still maintaining the accuracy of the 3- and 4-class?

Comment: I believe they have a pretty robust sentence annotator you can tune for such cases. Also, in general ML models tend to learn language characteristics and perform worse on different styles / domains. I'd suggest training a new model with documents from your domain.

Comment: The english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz seems to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Adding dot(.) at the end of each line gives better results. (Since sentence splitter uses dot as delimeter)